# Ajax Data table Codeigniter query return only one row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I am Using codeigniter to generate a ajax data-table and passing condition as User Id to fetch the records form a product orders table.

```
$this->datatables->select('orders.order_user_id,orders.order_date,orders.order_id,orders.order_confirmation_status,orders.order_payment_status,orders.order_shipping_status,orders.order_delivery_status,orders.order_packing_status')
        ->join('order_products','order_products.order_id=orders.order_id')
        ->select('round(sum(order_products.pr_quantity*order_products.pr_price))')
        ->where('orders.order_user_id',$this->uri->segment(3))
        ->unset_column('orders.order_confirmation_status')
        ->unset_column('orders.order_payment_status')
        ->unset_column('orders.order_shipping_status')
        ->unset_column('orders.order_delivery_status')
        ->unset_column('orders.order_packing_status')


        ->add_column('status', '$1','purchase_details_status(orders.order_confirmation_status,orders.order_packing_status,orders.order_shipping_status,orders.order_delivery_status)')

        ->add_column('action', '$1','purchase_details_action(orders.order_confirmation_status,orders.order_packing_status,orders.order_shipping_status,orders.order_delivery_status,orders.order_id)')

        ->from('orders');

        echo $this->datatables->generate();

        }
```

Here i Pass user_id in Where Condition. I have 10 records in database.but the table generate only one row.how to do this like `foreach` in codeigniter to get all 10 records.

Comment: is `datables` a plugin/library? if so, provide the link to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

you are echoing only the first element of the result,
so put your result in a variable and loop through it

```
$results = $this->datatables->generate();
foreach ($results as $row)
{
   print_r($row);
}
```

I hope that helps